# Cocoa Screensaver plugin with bundled custom frameworks

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, frameworks, screensaver

My app is partitioned into a number of frameworks.
Each framework has its **Installation Directory** set to `@executable_path/../Frameworks`, is linked and copied to the main executables Frameworks folder. All is working great.

Now some of the same frameworks are used in a separate screen saver executable.

The frameworks are linked, copied, present in the actual binary -
yet the screensaver module will fail to load with the following error:

```
Error loading /Users/someuser/Library/Screen Savers/MyScreenSaver.saver/Contents/MacOS/MyScreenSaver:  dlopen(/Users/someuser/Library/Screen Savers/MyScreenSaver.saver/Contents/MacOS/MyScreenSaver, 265): Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/BusinessBase.framework/Versions/A/BusinessBase
  Referenced from: /Users/someuser/Library/Screen Savers/MyScreenSaver.saver/Contents/MacOS/MyScreenSaver
  Reason: image not found
```

Looks like the screen saver (loaded as a plugin) cannot find the frameworks referenced by itself.

I've tried setting the screen savers **Framework Search Path** to both `@loader_path/../Frameworks` and `@executable_path/../Frameworks`.
No luck.

Any ideas what else to try..?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I've managed to fix this issue with some `install_name_tool` magic in a post build script:

The key was to change `executable_path` to `loader_path` **and** use the correct *relative* paths for the binary calling the respective framework.

Comment: Can you give more details? I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For a screensaver plugin, `@executable_path` is the path to the ScreenSaverEngine executable that's loading your screensaver, or to System Preferences if it's running as a preview. It is **not** the path to your screensaver module! For that, you will need to use `@loader_path`.

Comment: Erm, yes - that's why I've answered half an hour earlier that my solution using `loader_path` instead works..?! ;-)